# Global logging and save log to file

Tags: python, logging

Given the following project structure:

```
/package1
   __ini__.py 
   module1.py
   module2.py

main.py
```

where *main.py* file imports the module inside package and use such modules.

In order to log all the operations including the ones inside *module1.py* and *module2.py* I simply add the following line in *main.py*:

```
import logging

logging.basicConfig(format=FORMAT, datefmt='%H:%M:%S', level=log.INFO)
```

And that works. If I want to store the log in a file than I do:

```
logging.basicConfig(filename=logname, format=FORMAT, datefmt='%H:%M:%S', level=log.INFO)
```

Everything is simple and works perfectly. **But what if I want to have both options?**
That is the output in the console and the file saved to memory. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you need to define a [logger](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html#loggers), create two [handlers](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html#handlers): one for the [console](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.handlers.html#logging.StreamHandler) and the other for the [file](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.handlers.html#logging.FileHandler) and attach handlers to the logger:

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger('my_logger')

formatter = logging.Formatter(FORMAT)

console_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
console_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(console_handler)

file_handler = logging.FileHandler(logname)
file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(file_handler)
```

See more examples [here](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html).

Hope that helps.

Comment: Ok. But do I have to define these loggers on each module?

Comment: @pyself nope, just once - in the entry/initialization point of your app/module. Then you can access the existing logger by `logger = logging.getLogger('my_logger')`.